# Warning when using NSolve to solve equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

```
M = 1/10;
sol = NSolve[{n == 1/(2 M) + e/Tan[2 e], e == 1/(2 M)*Sqrt[Exp[4 n] - (1 - 
      2*M*n)^2], 1/10 < e < 6, -1 < n < 1}, {e, n}];
```

It gives the warning that " NSolve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete"

and then plot the functions

```
ContourPlot[{n == 5 + e/Tan[2 e], 
e == 5*Sqrt[Exp[4 n] - (1 - 2/10*n)^2]}, {e, 1/100, 6.3}, {n, -3, 
3}, ContourStyle -> {Black, {Dashed, Red}}, 
Epilog -> {RGBColor[0.2, 0.1, 0.8], Thickness[0.005], 
Table[Circle[{e /. sol[[k]], n /. sol[[k]]}, 0.07], {k, 1, 4}]}, 
Axes -> True, Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 40, 
Prolog -> {Line[Table[{{k*Pi/2, -3}, {k*Pi/2, 3}}, {k, 1, 4}]]}]
```

it give the picture without circles at the point of intersection.It seems that the code

```
Epilog -> {RGBColor[0.2, 0.1, 0.8], Thickness[0.005], 
    Table[Circle[{e /. sol[[k]], n /. sol[[k]]}, 0.07], {k, 1, 4}]}
```

didn't work

the first is the problematic picture and the second is the targeted picture
[image]

```
       picture one
```

[image]

```
      picture two
```

Comment: Your code works with version 11.3. What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Since e is real, `25 E^(4 n) - (-5 + n)^2` must be greater zero. Than you can solve for `25 E^(4 n) - (-5 + n)^2 == e^2` . Further do

```
FullSimplify[
   ComplexExpand[n == 1/(2 M) + e/Tan[2 e], 
   TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], 1/10 < e < 6 && -1 < n < 1]

(*   -10 + 2 n + e Tan[e] == e Cot[e]   *)
```

this leads to

```
nsol = NSolve[{-10 + 2 n + e Tan[e] == e Cot[e], 
      25 E^(4 n) - (-5 + n)^2 == e^2, 1/10 < e < 6, -1 < n < 1}, {e,  n}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 30]

(*   {{e -> 1.43094865810295458384888304493, 
       n -> 0.0180132370706695599946060476995}, {e -> 
            2.87757745845758744317117387730, 
       n -> 0.0665106724899688922422774527454}, {e -> 
            4.34782164851352692158237679687, 
       n -> 0.133182763206777152207840057118}, {e -> 
            5.84137958607605208314996732776, 
       n -> 0.206480096302156530694105177369}}   *)
```

Test

```
{-10 + 2 n + e Tan[e] - e Cot[e], 
  Sqrt[25 E^(4 n) - (-5 + n)^2] - e} /. nsol

(*   {{0.*10^-28, 0.*10^-30}, {0.*10^-28, 0.*10^-30}, {0.*10^-28, 
       0.*10^-30}, {0.*10^-28, 0.*10^-29}}   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

M = 1/10;

sol = NSolve[
    {n == 1/(2 M) + e/Tan[2 e], 
     e == 1/(2 M)*Sqrt[Exp[4 n] - (1 - 2*M*n)^2],
     1/10 < e < 6, -1 < n < 1}, {e, n}] // Quiet;

ContourPlot[
 {n == 5 + e/Tan[2 e], e == 5*Sqrt[Exp[4 n] - (1 - 2/10*n)^2]},
 {e, 1/100, 6.3}, {n, -3, 3},
 ContourStyle -> {Black, {Dashed, Red}},
 Epilog -> {RGBColor[0.2, 0.1, 0.8], Thickness[0.005],
   Circle[{e, n}, 0.07] /. sol},
 Axes -> True,
 Frame -> False,
 PlotPoints -> 40,
 Prolog -> {Line[{{#, -3}, {#, 3}} & /@ (Range[1, 4] Pi/2)]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** With version 10.3, `NSolve` is **much slower** and produces imaginary artifacts that can be removed with [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html)

```
$Version

(* "10.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)" *)

M = 1/10;
sol = Cases[
     NSolve[
      {n == 1/(2 M) + e/Tan[2 e], 
       e == 1/(2 M)*Sqrt[Exp[4 n] - (1 - 2*M*n)^2],
       1/10 < e < 6, -1 < n < 1}, {e, n},
      Reals],
     _?(FreeQ[#, Undefined] &)] // Chop // Quiet;

ContourPlot[{n == 5 + e/Tan[2 e], e == 5*Sqrt[Exp[4 n] - (1 - 2/10*n)^2]}, {e,
   1/100, 6.3}, {n, -3, 3},
 ContourStyle -> {Black, {Dashed, Red}}, 
 Epilog -> {RGBColor[0.2, 0.1, 0.8], Thickness[0.005], 
   Circle[{e, n}, 0.07] /. sol},
 Axes -> True,
 Frame -> False,
 PlotPoints -> 40,
 Prolog -> {Line[{{#, -3}, {#, 3}} & /@ (Range[1, 4] Pi/2)]}]
```

[image]

Comment: The version I used is 10.3.@Bob Hanlon

Comment: @Number_9527 - edit above added solution using version 10.3.1